# How can I do that a web page that is loaded in a cellphone allways send the request or data through the wifi network instead of the celullar network?

Tags: android, server, esp8266, cellular-network, esp8266wifi

I'm making a project where I have a web server in ESP mcu, the idea is control what I need through web pages, right now the server is working well but testing it on cellphones I noted that when both wifi and celullar networks are enabled the requests allways are made through the celullar network.

So, I need to force the request to travel through the wifi network allways, can someone point me on the right direction?.

Thanks in advance for the help.

right, now, I expect to solve the problem